# Groovy/Grails Tool Suite not configuring build path to use Spock plugin

Tags: grails

I'd like to use the Spock plugin for my Grails project.  The problem that I'm having is that GGTS doesn't configure the build path.  So I can generate the following integration test in GGTS, but it will then complain about not being able to find the grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec package.

```
package junk

import grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec

class MyIntegrationTestSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
    }
}
```

I've used both the Grails Plugin manager and editing the BuildConfig.groovy file (like the plugin documentation says to do).  I've done a Grails Refresh Dependencies on my project.  I even did a grails clean and grails compile.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: can you post your buildConfig, where you are adding the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Spock plugin page](http://grails.org/plugin/spock) explains how to configure your `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  repositories {
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
  }
  plugins {
    test(":spock:0.7") {
      exclude "spock-grails-support"
    }
  }
}
```

After that you need to run:

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

Or in STS:

```
right click in the project > grails tools > refresh dependencies
```

Comment: I was using the wrong configuration.  I was using the one for Grails 2.0/2.1 instead of Grails 2.2.  I have Grails 2.2.4